# Add photo to place with Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I noticed that GET request on place search with Google Places API sometimes respond with a photos object which looks alike this:

```
"photos" : [
     {
        "height" : 270,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110354877626525435377/photos\"\u003eFranck Moulinier\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAD_gs_sDA2mV2N4IAc-3LrIxEQU0Db0jo3Mizk4MDFWYe1IM0BCD03jr1v2QCg24XqfkOs5_ztg3kGQVCd8YNr_H97jkFC970-oHP86miLvXvHDh5skCwVpWsftZ-MxqxX4_l8WYSEaGgUcfnS5KL03-DBA8-S6HCo_gbYC9jF7bEhDHZMsHhbgom825iS-av2LTGhQ6LcPSmy0g7PheNuiFNAlGiKUXOQ",
        "width" : 270
     },
     {
        "height" : 518,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110354877626525435377/photos\"\u003eFranck Moulinier\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAEu8V-GUdxdJY8W04iZVTVdB3k7LdHxMpLZh24IIIJ88zm_CJkLSKwhj4RSqTGAH8xtTFRAKIiHh_l2GyZx8g2OUojN0lNOUtAiUE7zprFT3rJ6Y20cGjNpdQ7jccVOg3DOZP2vAA9RLHPsjs4IY1kJDAi83e25WkAokLBDY43_0EhBZYpHUv0ElrKrChz7PgkF7GhT-Xz0hdarNFVlz8OZJXrU9KEil8A",
        "width" : 800
     },
     {
        "height" : 485,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110354877626525435377/photos\"\u003eFranck Moulinier\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAFKpEYwIPFiRu2ccpPIfB_PmmHuiNlAnqgaGRt6mJ4FbSQdRjNW1mv3hP90Twyb2XeNEdyaYselLmrI7bu5egQeCVkvaG_IxKwgbXxL9h5lke4z0O44KStJdPk4hqsg8nNbuF5lp_Qe23MvB24r26pCS_j0_au4ftSnWIRiR_UY7EhAZSylqsZuFi_1AJlTg9fMaGhQlZn2ukuIjytpfVAPVETjRgTuTRg",
        "width" : 840
     },
     {
        "height" : 544,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110354877626525435377/photos\"\u003eFranck Moulinier\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAA9cxa3nipj_jYYzUgyVCFXGvurTnBU5IkWgcqYf1sR_Adqj7S3neoPyoVebI0G7C6hFK5m7-YOWnXZrXH9HDEsp7cX3am1SG34Rb2mg-_WzXoLs-4Z75DK060h7iusyTHz1bzSda3Tv_skJYR7QkBKVZt2wCbicUvFnSsTYccxdEhCivONHvfNPRTfnm42sh6g2GhRtkE1CV6HxACVOiu9KHR0ToRng3g",
        "width" : 800
     }
  ],
```

My question is simple: how can I add photos with a POST place add request on Google Places API? Place Photos seems to be read-only.

EDIT:
To be more specific, I'm calling Google Places API from my web-app in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google My Business API. It allows to submit photos to your locations:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations#Location

Comment: Well, I should have mentioned I'm calling Google Places API from a PHP webapp. I edited my post.

Comment: Places API doesn't have this functionality, but Google My Business API has. With Google My Business API you can POST photos of places that you own.

Comment: Ok, I'll check from this side. I have submitted the form, I've been told that it takes about 2 weeks to enable that API. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Well, I've implemented Google My Business API usage in my app. It seems that places I'm trying to add need to be "verified" to add photos. How does that verification process work?

Comment: There is a help article about verification https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778?hl=en

Comment: I don't get it. I've already seen that link, and it seems to be about claiming a business for your account. Is it the same thing as verifying your account? (i.e does claming a business will set a state 'VERIFIED' on my account)